# Heroku PostgresApp - Fails to start with edited postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am trying to tune my local pg running from the [Heroku Postgress App](http://postgresapp.com/).

I am seeing strange errors in the OSX console whenever I change some of the internal settings:

```
 PM Postgres[78709]: Could not connect the action selectPostgresStatus: to target of class AppDelegate
```

In the above case, setting `wal_buffers` to any value other than the default in the conf results in PG being inaccessible.

Other config settings have a similar effect.

Is there a trick to configuring Postgres.app?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a kernel resources issue. Check the PostgreSQL log files to see for sure. They should be in the `pg_log` directory, alongside `postgresql.conf`.

The PostgreSQL documentation on [kernel resources](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html) has a section on increasing shared memory limits for Mac OS X.

Note that increasing some settings in `postgresql.conf` also requires you to increase `shared_buffers`. This is usually documented in the info about that configuration option on the PostgreSQL site, and you'll be told in the PostgreSQL logs if you need to increase `shared_buffers`.